# How to use a pointer as token attribute in Boost::Spirit::Lex?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-lex

I write a minimum example to demonstrate this problem. It parses nested list of numbers like `(1 2 3 (4 5) (6 (7 (8))))`. I use spirit::lex to parse number and spirit::qi to parse list, so I code like this:

```cpp
using TokenTypes = boost::mpl::vector<Object*>;
using Iterator = std::string::iterator;

class Lexer : public lex::lexer<actor_lexer<token<Iterator, TokenTypes>>>
{
public:
  lex::token_def<> spaces;        // used to skip spaces
  lex::token_def<Object*> number; // create Number Object on heap and use the pointer as attribute

public:
  Lexer();
};

template<typename... Ts>
using Rule = qi::rule<Lexer::iterator_type, Ts...>;

class Parser : public qi::grammar<Lexer::iterator_type, Object*>
{
public:
  Lexer lexer;

  Rule<Object*> list;
  Rule<Object*> elem;

public:
  Parser();
};
```

But in `Parser::Parser()`, I can't use Lexer::number in gramma expression:

```cpp
Parser::Parser()
  : base_type(elem)
{
  // list = ...

  elem %= list | lexer.number; // fail to compile!
}
```

Clang error message (brief):

```
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:42:36: error: type 'Object *' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
          : is_iter_range<typename C::value_type> {};
                                   ^
...
...
...
```

I can't understand why this is wrong considering it used to work fine when I use other scalar types like `int` and `double` as token attribute.

**So, how to use pointer type as token attribute?**

### complete example

```cpp
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Object
{
public:
  virtual ~Object() = default;

public:
  virtual void print(std::ostream& out) = 0;
};

class Number : public Object
{
public:
  int64_t _val;

public:
  virtual void print(std::ostream& out) override { out << _val; }
};

class List : public Object
{
public:
  std::vector<Object*> _objs;

public:
  virtual void print(std::ostream& out) override
  {
    out << '(';
    for (auto&& i : _objs) {
      i->print(out);
      out << ' ';
    }
    out << ')';
  }
};

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace fu = boost::fusion;
namespace lex = boost::spirit::lex;

using lex::lexertl::actor_lexer;
using lex::lexertl::token;

using TokenTypes = boost::mpl::vector<Object*>;
using Iterator = std::string::iterator;

class Lexer : public lex::lexer<actor_lexer<token<Iterator, TokenTypes>>>
{
public:
  lex::token_def<> spaces;
  lex::token_def<Object*> number;

public:
  Lexer();
};

template<typename... Ts>
using Rule = qi::rule<Lexer::iterator_type, Ts...>;

class Parser : public qi::grammar<Lexer::iterator_type, Object*>
{
public:
  Lexer lexer;

  Rule<Object*, qi::locals<List*>> list;
  Rule<Object*> elem;

public:
  Parser();
};

Lexer::Lexer()
{
  self += '(';
  self += ')';

  spaces = R"(\s+)";
  self +=
    spaces[([](auto& start, auto& end, auto& matched, auto& id, auto& ctx) {
      matched = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore;
    })];

  number = R"(\d+)";
  self +=
    number[([](auto& start, auto& end, auto& matched, auto& id, auto& ctx) {
      auto val = new Number();
      auto iter = start;
      qi::parse(iter, end, qi::long_long, val->_val);
      ctx.set_value(val);
    })];
}

Parser::Parser()
  : base_type(elem)
{
  list = (         //
    qi::lit('(')[( //
      [](auto& attr, auto& ctx, bool& pass) {
        fu::at_c<0>(ctx.locals) = new List();
      })]       //
    >> *(elem[( //
         [](auto& attr, auto& ctx, bool& pass) {
           List* list = fu::at_c<0>(ctx.locals);
           list->_objs.push_back(attr);
         })]) //
    >> ')'    //
    )[(       //
    [](auto& attr, auto& ctx, bool& pass) {
      List* list = fu::at_c<0>(ctx.locals);
      fu::at_c<0>(ctx.attributes) = list;
    })];

  elem %= list | lexer.number;
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Parser parser;

  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    auto begin = line.begin();
    Object* obj;
    lex::tokenize_and_parse(begin, line.end(), parser.lexer, parser, obj);
    obj->print(std::cout);
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. Don't take this badly. Reading your sample (kudos for including a self-contained example! This saves a ton of time) I can't help but feeling that you've somehow stumbled on the worst possible cross-section of anti-patterns in Spirit Qi.

1. You're using a polymorphic AST:

   - [How can I use polymorphic attributes with boost::spirit::qi parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299722/how-can-i-use-polymorphic-attributes-with-boostspiritqi-parsers/23301519#23301519)
   - [Semantic actions runs multiple times in boost::spirit parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911950/semantic-actions-runs-multiple-times-in-boostspirit-parsing/37912787#37912787)
   - [Parsing inherited struct with boost spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56872966/parsing-inherited-struct-with-boost-spirit/56875531#56875531)
2. You're using semantic actions. As a rule this already misses the sweet spot for embedded grammars, which is why I linked [126 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/8259440?sort=hot) to [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil).

   However, that's even just talking about semantic actions for Qi. You **also** use them for Lex:

   ```
   self +=
       spaces[([](auto& start, auto& end, auto& matched, auto& id,
                  auto& ctx) { matched = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore; })];
   ```

   Which is then further complicated by *not* using Phoenix, e.g.:

   ```
   self += spaces[lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore];
   ```

   Which does exactly the same but with about 870% less noise and equal amounts of evil magic.
3. The other semantic action tops it all:

   ```
   self += number[(
       [](auto& start, auto& end, auto& matched, auto& id, auto& ctx) {
           auto val = new Number();
           auto iter = start;
           qi::parse(iter, end, qi::long_long, val->_val);
           ctx.set_value(val);
       })];
   ```

   Besides having all the problems already listed, it literally makes a fractal out of things by **calling Qi from a Lex semantic action**. Of course, this wants to be:

   ```
   self += number[lex::_val = phx::new_<Number>(/*magic*/)];
   ```

   But that magic doesn't exist. My gut feeling is that your issue that the Lexer shouldn't be concerned with AST types *at all*. At this point I feel that the lexer could/should be something like

   ```
   using TokenTypes = boost::mpl::vector<uint64_t>;
   using Iterator = std::string::const_iterator; // NOTE const_

   struct Lexer : lex::lexer<actor_lexer<token<Iterator, TokenTypes>>> {
       lex::token_def<>         spaces;
       lex::token_def<uint64_t> number;

       Lexer() : spaces{R"(\s+)"}, number{R"(\d+)"} {
           self += '(';
           self += ')';
           self += spaces[lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore];
           self += number;
       }
   };
   ```

   That is, if it should exist at all.

That's the structural assessment. Let me apply simplifications to the Qi grammar along the same lines, just so we can reason about the code:

```
struct Parser : qi::grammar<Lexer::iterator_type, Object*()> {
    Parser() : base_type(elem) {
        using namespace qi::labels;

        static constexpr qi::_a_type _list{};
        const auto _objs = phx::bind(&List::_objs, _list);

        list = (                               //
            '(' >>                             //
            *(elem[phx::push_back(_objs, _1)]) //
            >> ')'                             //
            )[_val = phx::new_<List>(_list)];

        elem                  //
            = list[_val = _1] //
            | lexer.number[_val = phx::new_<Number>(_1)];
    }

    Lexer lexer; // TODO FIXME excess scope

  private:
    using It = Lexer::iterator_type;
    qi::rule<It, Object*(), qi::locals<List>> list;
    qi::rule<It, Object*()>                    elem;
};
```

Note how I made the local `List` instead of `List*`, to just slightly reduce the chance of memory leaks. I guess for efficiency you could try to make Phoenix do move-semantics for you:

```
 [_val = phx::new_<List>(phx::static_cast_<List&&>(_list))];
```

But at that point I wouldn't trust all the expression templates to do what you want and go to the more elaborate (even assuming c++17):

```
phx::function move_new = [](List& l) { return new List(std::move(l)); };

list = (                               //
    '(' >>                             //
    *(elem[phx::push_back(_objs, _1)]) //
    >> ')'                             //
    )[_val = move_new(_list)];
```

Now we arrive at a workable demo:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6714e4d3684bc094)**

```
int main() {
    Parser parser;

    for (std::string const line : {
             "",
             "42",
             "()",
             "(1 2 3)",
             "(1 (44 55 () 66) 3)",
         }) {
        auto    begin = line.begin();
        Object* obj = nullptr;
        if (lex::tokenize_and_parse(begin, line.end(), parser.lexer, parser,
                                    obj)) {
            obj->print(std::cout << std::quoted(line) << " -> ");
            delete obj;
        } else {
            std::cout << std::quoted(line) << " -> FAILED";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Printing

```
"" -> FAILED
"42" -> 42
"()" -> ()
"(1 2 3)" -> (1 2 3 )
"(1 (44 55 () 66) 3)" -> (1 (44 55 () 66 ) 3 )
```

Note that this simple test program **ALREADY** leaks 11 objects, for a total of 224 bytes. That's not even complicating things with error-handling or backtracking rules.

That's **craziness**. You could of course fix it with smart pointers, but that just further complicates everything while making sure performance will be very poor.

### Further Simplifications

I would stop using Lex and dynamic polymorphism:

#### No More Lex:

The only "value" Lex is adding here is skipping spaces. Qi is very capable (see e.g. [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965) for variations on that theme), so we'll use `skip(space)[]` instead:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a4914127d2ad183)**

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Object {
    virtual ~Object() = default;
    virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const = 0;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Object const& o) { return o.print(os), os; }
};

struct Number : Object {
    Number(uint64_t v = 0) : _val(v) {}
    int64_t      _val;
    virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const override { out << _val; }
};

struct List : Object {
    std::vector<Object*> _objs;

    virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const override {
        out << '(';
        for (auto&& el : _objs)
            out << ' ' << *el;
        out << ')';
    }
};

namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

template <typename It>
struct Parser : qi::grammar<It, Object*()> {
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi::labels;

        static constexpr qi::_a_type _list{};
        const auto _objs = phx::bind(&List::_objs, _list);

        phx::function move_new = [](List& l) { return new List(std::move(l)); };

        list = (                               //
            '(' >>                             //
            *(elem[phx::push_back(_objs, _1)]) //
            >> ')'                             //
            )[_val = move_new(_list)];

        elem                                          //
            = list[_val = _1]                         //
            | qi::uint_[_val = phx::new_<Number>(_1)] //
            ;

        start = qi::skip(qi::space)[elem];
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, Object*(), qi::space_type, qi::locals<List>> list;
    qi::rule<It, Object*(), qi::space_type> elem;

    // lexemes
    qi::rule<It, Object*()> start;
};

int main() {
    Parser<std::string::const_iterator> const parser;

    for (std::string const line : {
             "",
             "42",
             "()",
             "(1 2 3)",
             "(1 (44 55 () 66) 3)",
         }) {
        Object* obj = nullptr;
        if (parse(line.begin(), line.end(), parser >> qi::eoi, obj)) {
            std::cout << std::quoted(line) << " -> " << *obj;
        } else {
            std::cout << std::quoted(line) << " -> FAILED";
        }
        delete obj;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Still leaking like C++ went out of fashion, but at least doing so in 20 fewer LoC and half the compile time.

#### Static Polymorphism

Hiding all the raw pointer stuff (or avoiding it completely, depending on the exact AST requirements):

```
using Number = uint64_t;
using Object = boost::make_recursive_variant< //
    Number,                                   //
    std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_>>::type;

using List   = std::vector<Object>;
```

> For ease of supplying `operator<<` I moved them into an `AST` namespace below.

The parser goes down to:

```
template <typename It> struct Parser : qi::grammar<It, AST::Object()> {
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(start) {
        list = '(' >> *elem >> ')';
        elem = list | qi::uint_;

        start = qi::skip(qi::space)[elem];
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, AST::List(), qi::space_type> list;
    qi::rule<It, AST::Object(), qi::space_type> elem;
    qi::rule<It, AST::Object()> start;
};
```

No more lex, no more phoenix, no more leaks, no more manual semantic actions. Just, expressive code.

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/151c45fe6b9b2fce)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace AST {
    struct Number {
        uint64_t v;
        Number(uint64_t v = 0) : v(v){};
    };

    using Object = boost::make_recursive_variant< //
        Number,                                   //
        std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_>>::type;

    using List = std::vector<Object>;

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Number const& n) {
        return os << n.v;
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, List const& l) {
        os << '(';
        for (auto& el : l)
            os << ' ' << el;
        return os << ')';
    }
} // namespace AST

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It> struct Parser : qi::grammar<It, AST::Object()> {
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(start) {
        list = '(' >> *elem >> ')';
        elem = list | qi::uint_;

        start = qi::skip(qi::space)[elem];
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, AST::List(), qi::space_type> list;
    qi::rule<It, AST::Object(), qi::space_type> elem;
    qi::rule<It, AST::Object()> start;
};

int main() {
    Parser<std::string::const_iterator> const parser;

    for (std::string const line : {
             "",
             "42",
             "()",
             "(1 2 3)",
             "(1 (44 55 () 66) 3)",
         }) {
        AST::Object obj;
        if (parse(line.begin(), line.end(), parser >> qi::eoi, obj))
            std::cout << std::quoted(line) << " -> " << obj << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << std::quoted(line) << " -> FAILED\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"" -> FAILED
"42" -> 42
"()" -> ()
"(1 2 3)" -> ( 1 2 3)
"(1 (44 55 () 66) 3)" -> ( 1 ( 44 55 () 66) 3)
```

But this time, without leaking memory. And also, it now compiles fast enough that [Compiler Explorer can also handle it](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/hErdE4vYz).

Comment: BONUS: Since you're using c++14 anyways, further reduce the code and compilation times with X3: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/4v3fEb1a6 - Incidentally, it will [allow you to write semantics that match your expected style](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/tutorials/semantic_actions.html) if you ever do need them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I get your points. I was writing a Lisp interpreter and trying to make the parser to output the `cons` objects directly. Now I understand that I'd better keep the spirit ast and use boost::apply_visitor to transform it into lisp representation. : ) @sehe

Comment: That's what I usually do, indeed!

Comment: But I still have a question: It seems that you don't recommend using lex. The reason I use lex here is to parse some context-sensitive gramma like raw string `R"abc(some text)abc"`. I think it's proper to parse such structure in lexical analysis. Is it possible to get rid of lex even in such scenario? @sehe

Comment: I don't know what "proper" means for you. Is it possible during lexing? Likely. Is it necessary? No. Does it add value? I don't think so? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b463337345fe07a7

Comment: Oh oops, I over-simplified. Here's with correct attribute propagation: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ca7c6ecf7e8ea23

Answer (score 0):

Found a walkaround: use `std::size_t` and `reinterpret_cast` to replace pointer types:

```cpp
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Object
{
public:
  virtual ~Object() = default;

public:
  virtual void print(std::ostream& out) = 0;
};

class Number : public Object
{
public:
  int64_t _val;

public:
  virtual void print(std::ostream& out) override { out << _val; }
};

class List : public Object
{
public:
  std::vector<Object*> _objs;

public:
  virtual void print(std::ostream& out) override
  {
    out << '(';
    for (auto&& i : _objs) {
      i->print(out);
      out << ' ';
    }
    out << ')';
  }
};

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace fu = boost::fusion;
namespace lex = boost::spirit::lex;

using lex::lexertl::actor_lexer;
using lex::lexertl::token;

using TokenTypes = boost::mpl::vector<std::size_t>;
using Iterator = std::string::iterator;

class Lexer : public lex::lexer<actor_lexer<token<Iterator, TokenTypes>>>
{
public:
  lex::token_def<> spaces;
  lex::token_def<std::size_t> number; // use std::size_t instead

public:
  Lexer();
};

template<typename... Ts>
using Rule = qi::rule<Lexer::iterator_type, Ts...>;

class Parser : public qi::grammar<Lexer::iterator_type, Object*>
{
public:
  Lexer lexer;

  Rule<Object*, qi::locals<List*>> list;
  Rule<Object*> elem;

public:
  Parser();
};

Lexer::Lexer()
{
  self += '(';
  self += ')';

  spaces = R"(\s+)";
  self +=
    spaces[([](auto& start, auto& end, auto& matched, auto& id, auto& ctx) {
      matched = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore;
    })];

  number = R"(\d+)";
  self +=
    number[([](auto& start, auto& end, auto& matched, auto& id, auto& ctx) {
      auto val = new Number();
      auto iter = start;
      qi::parse(iter, end, qi::long_long, val->_val);
      ctx.set_value(reinterpret_cast<std::size_t>(val)); // cast here
    })];
}

Parser::Parser()
  : base_type(elem)
{
  list = (         //
    qi::lit('(')[( //
      [](auto& attr, auto& ctx, bool& pass) {
        fu::at_c<0>(ctx.locals) = new List();
      })]       //
    >> *(elem[( //
         [](auto& attr, auto& ctx, bool& pass) {
           List* list = fu::at_c<0>(ctx.locals);
           list->_objs.push_back(attr);
         })]) //
    >> ')'    //
    )[(       //
    [](auto& attr, auto& ctx, bool& pass) {
      List* list = fu::at_c<0>(ctx.locals);
      fu::at_c<0>(ctx.attributes) = list;
    })];

  elem %= list | qi::omit[lexer.number[([](auto& attr, auto& ctx, bool& pass) {
            fu::at_c<0>(ctx.attributes) = reinterpret_cast<Object*>(attr); // cast here
          })]];
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Parser parser;

  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    auto begin = line.begin();
    Object* obj;
    lex::tokenize_and_parse(begin, line.end(), parser.lexer, parser, obj);
    obj->print(std::cout);
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I think this is **really ugly**. Anyone has a better solution???

Comment: Gut response: 1. Do'nt use lex. And 2. Don't use pointers. I'll look at the question in ... a few hours today

Comment: A few hours [have passed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72501358/85371)